How to recover midstream from a stack buffer overrun
This question is out of my expertise. How do you recover, midstream, from a stack overflow overrun in "C"?
Where you are using a character variable declared as char string[12], and you move 12 characters to where you only have space for 11 characters.  How do you detect a stack overflow overrun midstream? If you do detect an overrun, how do you fix the problem and carry on as normal?
The way I'm doing it is this:
  character dform[12];
  strcpy(dform,"june-11-2024"); when it should have been strcpy(dform,"jun-11-2024")
  checkdate(dform); /// you have just invoked a stack buffer overrun, as you've passed on into a subroutine. 
///  dform is only suppose to hold 11 characters and not 12 characters. 
////    the 12th character causes the stack buffer overrun. 

How do I detect it midstream, and if so, fix the problem midstream and then carry on with business as normal from within a subroutine and then pass back the corrected value.
Have tried many work arounds with no success. But want to nip it in the bud and then fix it and carry on. (It reminds me of C#' exception handling capability.)

If you have an array, you need to keep track of the size of the array. Whenever you try to use an index into the array, compare it to the array range (not negative, not equal or larger than the size). If you have already gone out of bounds, it's really too late to do anything useful.

Not recovering, preventing is the way to go. strncpy would be the way to go, our you could check with strlen in advance and then do memcpy.

you can't. It's undefined behaviour and your program is in a state that can't be predicted.

OT: character dform[12]; ==> char dform[12];... If you're writing for a modern CPU (2+Gb of memory), there's no reason to use buffers that are as small as possible. Using, say, [32] would remove this problem. Then you go on to make sure everything else is clean and correct...

I haven't really paid attention what's happening with C standard, but you should use strcpy_s or equivalent to eliminate the possibility of buffer overruns.

Lateral thinking: Send both the destination buffer and the "source string" to the check() function as is. Let the function do its thing, including checking the length as its first QC check... If everything is alright, it can then make a copy into dform[12] (if required) as its final act before returning...

@Aconcagua Bad advice, strncpy has nothing to do with null terminated strings and can only be used with them by accident. It is a dangerous, obsolete function from the dark ages. Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?

@TanveerBadar The bounds-checking interface that was introduced with C11 was a complete fiasco and nobody implemented it. Support for strcpy_s is mixed, to the point where it should be considered a non-standard extension similar to strlcpy.

@Lundin We could fix/mitigate by always placing a null character at last array position afterwards – we'd then be safe again… But need to agree, though I see far more critical detecting if strings have actually been cut off (if critical). Unfortunately the return value is the same as one of the input pointers. It would have been fare more useful to return a pointer to the last position written to (if(*retval) { /* cut off, error handling */ } else { /*null terminated anyway*/ } – or simply *retval = 0;` if cutting off is fine). And yes, there's the overhead of filling up the remainder, too.

@Aconcagua With C23 you can do memccpy(dst, src, '\0', n) Same deal as strncpy but less misleading name - neither function knows anything about null terminated strings as such. But at least with memccpy you won't assume that it inserts a null terminator and you'll therefore always add one manually.

@Lundin Oh, that's a good one, wasn't aware of. Especially the differentiated return value is great (if(!retval) { /* need to null-terminate or error handling for cutting off*/ }). I'll keep that in mind ;)

You don't.  It's unrecoverable.
dform holds 12 characters including the trailing null, and by that same token you've written 13.  Some other piece of the code may well have been storing something important in that following byte, and once you have overwritten it, there's no way of knowing what it was.  And you can readily imagine scenarios where the consequences of writing zero over a single byte are arbitrarily bad (e.g. it contained bool avert_global_armageddon = true;.)
If the following byte happens to be on an unmapped page, it's theoretically possible on some systems to catch the SIGSEGV signal and recover, as in that case no data was actually overwritten.  But that is actually very unlikely for a bug like you describe.
If you know how to detect an overrun, then do it before the access in question, and if you determine that an overrun would occur, don't do it!
If by some means you do determine after the fact that something like a buffer overrun occurred, you need to abort the program immediately (e.g. abort()).  Continuing to execute might do more damage (e.g. corrupting more memory or data) or allow an attacker to carry out an exploit.

Sadly, not necessarily "fatal".  Since it's UB, the program could continue and you might not discover the problem until other users are running it.

@TobySpeight I wouldn't consider running with a known land mine planted somewhere in the address space safe.

Nor would I @Andrew - but just like a physical landmine, you still don't know whether or not you'll get through unscathed.  And surviving doesn't tell you there are no mines present.  It's quite a good analogy, really.  BTW, I'm just quibbling with that one word.  Lots of good alternatives exist ("dangerous", "reckless", whatever).

@TobySpeight: I changed it to "unrecoverable".  You're right that I didn't mean "fatal" in the sense of "inevitably causing program termination".


you are using a character variable declared as charstring[12], and you move 12 character; where you only have space for 11 characters. Now, How do you detect a stack overflow overrun midstream.

No point in detecting overflow after it has happened, because then your program is already in an unpredictable state due to invoking undefined behavior.
Consider:
const char *date = "june-11-2024";

if (strlen(date) < sizeof dform) {
    strcpy(dform, date);
} else {
    // handle error here
}

Or use a bigger buffer size, or allocate memory dynamically with malloc() and family.

How do I detect it midstream, and if so, fix the problem midstream and then carry on with business as normal from within a subroutine and then pass back the corrected value.

It can't be fixed. Assuming you do detect it afterwards, call abort().
Aside: There's no data type named character in C. You meant char.

Redundancy by duplicate string literals invites for future maintenance errors (editing one, forgetting the other) – storing in a char const* variable or having a #define would mitigate that. Once the length is known anyway I'd prefer memcpy for efficiency.

@Aconcagua We're in accord, but I was going along with OP's example. I'll edit it.

As others have pointed out, the correct, concise answer to your question is that the code you've shown (with "june-...") is not a valid C program because it invokes UB (because of buffer overrun). All bets are off.

On the other hand, let's presume that the required format is to be "MMM-DD-YYYY" and messed-up incoming data (or compile time strings) may be salvageable. The unknown function checkdate() will have to be both robust and have an understanding of the source data.
char dform[12];
strcpy( dform, checkdate( "june-11-2024" ) );

could work.
I'm presuming, here, that checkdate will "disassemble" the string to check that "feb-31-2000" will result in program termination, or an expected "error" value (eg: "jan-01-1970") that can be processed and found & corrected downstream.
It might be even better if another parameter informed checkdate() of the destination buffer size, including its provision for the null terminator.

I'm very overwhelmed with all the responses.  A clarification is needed here. -
strcpy(dform,"june-11-2024");  When it should have been strcpy(dform,"jun-11-2024");
/// with the above strcpy statement executed, you've already invoked a system stack
buffer overrun error. As soon as you've returned from the called subroutine to check for it, the system will throw the system error and your program will ABend.  With a declaration of Dform[12],  it's meant to hold 11 characters plus the NULL only.  This variable is used as a parameter to a sub that does date/date_format verifications.

@CC_Fingers In the text of this answer I suggest checkdate() will be robust, and will have to disassemble whatever string it receives to perform its checks. OP wants to "continue processing" even with minor data problems. checkdate() could receive "April 1, 23" and return a static buffer filled with "apr-01-2023"... Humans are fallible; well-written programs can compensate and get the job done (if at all possible). Do you want your code to work, or to just fall-over at the slightest perturbance?

OKay.  Let's forget about the checkdate() function OK!
The point/issue at hand is that you've already assigned a character variable(char DForm[12]), to hold more that what you have previously declared it to hold. With that assignment, you've just
invoked a System exception error of a system stack buffer overrun error.  Now with that in mind,
how can I recover from that System error w/o my program ABending.  I'd would like to keep my
program running. I guess what I'm looking for is contained and used within C#, but I'm programming
in "C". It's C#'s  Exception Error handling feature.  Hum?

"how can I recover from that System error w/o my program ABending." All the answers have already answered this question of yours. You cannot reliably recover. Sometimes the memory corrupted is inconsequential and program runs to completion. Sometimes corruption causes immediate termination. "I guess what I'm looking for is contained and used within C#" C is not C#. You cannot watch YouTube on an old landline phone, but you can on a smartphone, and you can make calls on both. Apples are not oranges, even if both are round. Hum?
